# After a key rotation do I still need the old key to sign the update of the app?

Tags: android, android-signing, apksigner, apk-signing, key-rotation

I have read here, https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/apksigning/v3, and here https://www.xda-developers.com/apk-signature-scheme-v3-key-rotation/, that I rotate keys with the V3 signing and be able to sign the apk with another key.

Do I still need the old key to sign it? Or signing it with the new key is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, signed with new key is enough.

I did below key rotation steps on Android 13 emulator and Pixel 5 (not work on Android 10 Emulator)

below steps for you reference

create 3 key store owen1.jks, owen2.jks and owen3.jks

```
keytool -keystore owen1.jks -genkey -alias owen1 -keyalg rsa
keytool -keystore owen2.jks -genkey -alias owen2 -keyalg rsa
keytool -keystore owen3.jks -genkey -alias owen3 -keyalg rsa
```

create rotation lineage file

```
apksigner rotate --out SigningCertificateLineage.owen1.owen2 --old-signer --ks owen1.jks --new-signer --ks owen2.jks
apksigner rotate --out SigningCertificateLineage.owen2.owen3 --old-signer --ks owen2.jks --new-signer --ks owen3.jks
```

sign serial.apk with each jks

```
apksigner sign --ks owen1.jks --in serial.apk --out serial.SignedOwen1.apk
apksigner sign --ks owen2.jks --in serial.apk --out serial.SignedOwen2.apk
apksigner sign --ks owen3.jks --in serial.apk --out serial.SignedOwen3.apk
```

sign serial.apk with rotation data

```
apksigner sign --ks owen1.jks --next-signer --ks owen2.jks --lineage SigningCertificateLineage.owen1.owen2 --in serial.apk --out serial.rotate.owen1.owen2.apk
apksigner sign --ks owen2.jks --next-signer --ks owen3.jks --lineage SigningCertificateLineage.owen2.owen3 --in serial.apk --out serial.rotate.owen2.owen3.apk
```

then let’s try the rotation as below steps

```
[0] 12/29 15:41:51 owenwen@dell:~/jks$ adb install serial.SignedOwen1.apk
Performing Incremental Install
Serving...
All files should be loaded. Notifying the device.
Success
Install command complete in 931 ms
 
[0] 12/29 15:42:42 owenwen@dell:~/jks$ adb install serial.rotate.owen1.owen2.apk
Performing Incremental Install
Serving...
All files should be loaded. Notifying the device.
Success
Install command complete in 629 ms
 
[0] 12/29 15:42:52 owenwen@dell:~/jks$ adb install serial.SignedOwen2.apk
Performing Incremental Install
Serving...
All files should be loaded. Notifying the device.
Success
Install command complete in 467 ms
 
[0] 12/29 15:42:59 owenwen@dell:~/jks$ adb install serial.rotate.owen2.owen3.apk
Performing Incremental Install
Serving...
All files should be loaded. Notifying the device.
Success
Install command complete in 570 ms
 
[0] 12/29 15:43:05 owenwen@dell:~/jks$ adb install serial.SignedOwen3.apk
Performing Incremental Install
Serving...
All files should be loaded. Notifying the device.
Success
Install command complete in 728 ms
 
[0] 12/29 15:43:10 owenwen@dell:~/jks$ adb install serial.SignedOwen1.apk
Performing Incremental Install
Serving...
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Existing package com.sample.app signatures do not match newer version; ignoring!]
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install serial.SignedOwen1.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Existing package com.sample.app signatures do not match newer version; ignoring!]
 
[1] 12/29 15:43:14 owenwen@dell:~/jks$ adb shell getprop | grep fingerprint
[ro.bootimage.build.fingerprint]: [google/redfin/redfin:13/TQ1A.221205.011/9244662:user/release-keys]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @Wenchichin.
Did yo manage to make it work on Google play store?